# Save an array of pixels to a file

Tags: haxe

In the Haxe programming language, is there any cross-language way to save an array of pixel data to a file (e. g., in BMP or PNG format)?

```
class SavePixelsToFile {
  static function main(){
    //how can I save this array of pixel data to a file? It is a simple 2D array of RGB arrays, with the red, green, and blue components in the respective order.
    var arr = [
      [[0, 0, 0],[255, 255, 255]],
      [[255, 255, 255],[0, 0, 0]]
      ];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format library will do what you want. http://code.google.com/p/hxformat/

Install this library: haxelib install format

Link it in your hxml file using: -lib format

To write image data to a file, do the following:

```
function writePixels24(file:String, pixels:haxe.io.Bytes, width:Int, height:Int) {
    var handle = sys.io.File.write(file, true);
    new format.png.Writer(handle)
        .write(format.png.Tools.build24(width, height, pixels));
    handle.close();
}

var bo = new haxe.io.BytesOutput();
for (pixel in pixels)
    for (channel in pixel) 
         bo.writeByte(channel);
var bytes = bo.getBytes();
writePixels24("Somefile.png", bytes);
```

This will work for targets that have the sys.* package (Not flash). you can still generate the png without the sys.* package, but will need an alternate method of saving the file.

Comment: Thanks, I've been waiting all day for an answer to this question. :)

Answer (score 0):

An easy to write format is [PPM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html). The netpbm tools can easily manipulate those and also convert to many formats including [PBM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppmtobmp.html) and [PNG](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pnmtopng.html).

Comment: I don't see any mention of Haxe in the documentation. Specifically, is it possible to generate PPM files using a cross-language Haxe library (such as the Sys API)?